# Simple way to automate unit testing by logging an XML file and sending e-mail

Tags: xml, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, jenkins, command-line

I am new to the world of unit testing. I am currently setting up some unit+integration tests in the game engine Unity. I have a simple batch script that runs Unity via the command line and then outputs an XML file with the results (https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/wiki/UnitTestsRunner).

Below is an example of a succesful test that is logged by saving an XML file on my local computer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This file represents the results of running a test suite-->
<test-results name="Unity Tests" total="3" errors="0" failures="0" not-run="0" inconclusive="0" ignored="0" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2016-09-17" time="17:41:27">
  <environment nunit-version="2.6.2-Unity" clr-version="2.0.50727.1433" os-version="Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0" platform="Win32NT" cwd="C:\Users\UnitTesting_test" machine-name="Wikzo" user="Wikzo" user-domain="Wikzo" unity-version="5.4.0f3" unity-platform="StandaloneWindows" />
  <culture-info current-culture="en-US" current-uiculture="en-US" />
  <test-suite name="2_IntegrationTest" type="Assembly" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="4.060">
    <results>
      <test-case name="MoverTest" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="1.032">
        <reason>
          <message>
<![CDATA[Sent TestStarted
Pass 
]]>
          </message>
        </reason>
      </test-case>
      <test-case name="PowerUpTest" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="0.015">
        <reason>
          <message>
<![CDATA[Sent TestStarted
Pass 
]]>
          </message>
        </reason>
      </test-case>
      <test-case name="Sphere Drag Test" executed="True" result="Success" success="True" time="3.013">
        <reason>
          <message>
<![CDATA[Sent TestStarted
Pass (Plane)
]]>
          </message>
        </reason>
      </test-case>
    </results>
  </test-suite>
</test-results>
```

As I have never worked with XML nor automatic builds/testing before, I would like to get some pointers on how to approach this in a smart, yet simple, manner.

The plan right now is to run these tests via the command line in Windows every night on a local machine (maybe I will dive into servers and Jenkins in the future, but for now I am taking baby steps). Instead of manually having to read through the XML log, I would like to somehow get notified if the tests fail (result="Failure"). It would be nice if this could be done by e.g. sending me an e-mail or something similar that doesn't require too much setup.

How should I go about this? Is there an "IFTTT"-style of easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file looks a lot like the XML file produced by an NUnit test suite. Can you confirm if these tests are based on NUnit?

If that is the case, most build servers already contain components that parse these test output files. They also have features such as sending emails on failures etc. However, if you set up a build server like Jenkins then you won't need emails - you can just check the build server in the morning.

It is worth pointing out that you don't need a server to run Jenkins. It can be installed on your local machine without a problem.

Running tests and interpreting and reporting on the output is one of the main purposes of build servers - I highly recommend that you don't try to do this yourself and instead just embrace the existing solutions, particularly as Jenkins (and TeamCity to an extent) are free. Typically, they are easy to set up.

If you really don't want to do this, then the only way I see of doing this is to write a custom program that parses the XML file and inspects the relevant XML attributes, counting the failures.

I get that you don't want to invest in setting up a build server (although it doesn't have to be a server, can just be your local machine), but what happens when you want to add other steps to your build process? The custom programs you have written to inspect the output of your tests will quickly become a maintenance burden which will distract you from what you really want to be doing - writing your gaming code!

One more point to try to convince you - learning how to set up a build server such as Jenkins will pay off in the future if you start other projects or have technical interviews for jobs.

Comment: Also, when a test fails, a build server can help you browse the failures and display the relevant program output from the failing test. These features can be very handy when diagnosing failures.

Comment: It is indeed based on NUnit: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Will consider taking a deeper look at Jenkins soon :)

Comment: With Jenkins, is it possible to make it run my batch file on my local machine? Right now, I was just thinking about using the built-in Windows Scheduling to run my batch file on a specific time.

It's basically this:
>Unity.exe -runEditorTests 
-projectPath PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT 
-editorTestsResultFile C:\temp\results.xml
-editorTestsFilter Player

Comment: I figured it out myself. Now I can run my batch command via Jenkins :D Next up I will have to understand how to let Jenkins load/read the XML file.

Comment: Glad you decided to experiment with Jenkins :) The easiest way to get Jenkins to understand your xml file might be to use the Nunit plugin to run your tests instead of a batch script. Basically, you tell jenkins the name of your test dll and it will automatically discover and run the tests inside.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now. It was a bit tough to understand at first, but now it seems to work as I want it to: I can now initiate automatic tests on demand (next up: make it work with automatic Git pushes). Struggled a lot with getting Unity to talk to Jenkins (doing automatic builds and tests via the command line). Reading the XML file via the NUnit plugin was surprisingly simple. Thanks for asking me to try out Jenkins; you gave me a "challenge accepted" feeling, which made me spend the good half of my weekend trying to figure out Jenkins. And now I know how to use it! :)

Comment: That's great. And now you have Jenkins up and running, building automatically on git pushes should be straightforward! Good luck with the project.